# JavaScript, store for loop in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this stupid problem because jquery and javascript aren't that great of languages. As you can see here:

```
        let blokla = '<select>' + 
        test = function (info) { 
            for (i = 0; i < info.length; i++) { 
                '<option>' + info[i].title + '</option>' 
            } 
        } + '</select>';
```

I am trying to store  and  in a variable and  inbetween using for loop. I am using this variable so I can .replaceWith a button when I click on it.

I've tried to replace the + in the first line with , but no luck.

Comment: `...because jquery and javascript aren't that great of languages` I can't think of many languages which would let you define a function within a string, let alone a function with no purpose.

Comment: I think Javascript is a pretty great languages for a lot of purposes. I agree though that jQuery is not a great language. It's a great library.

Comment: @PriyankMotivaras I agree. However calling something 'not great' for that reason is incredibly fallacious

Comment: There's no need for `test= function(info)`. Just run the loop between the opening and closing `select` tags.

Comment: I think you'll find that people here will always respond with helpful information, usually within minutes of a post. And, you don't need to try to make your post more interesting. All you need to do is clearly explain the problem, what you've tried and what you are looking for. Please read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, use [JavaScript Assignment Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment)

```
function selectOption(){
  var blokla = '<select>';
  for (i = 0; i < info.length; i++) { 
    blokla += '<option>' + info[i].title + '</option>' 
  } 
  blokla += "</select>";

  return blokla;
}

console.log(selectOption())
```

Answer (score 2):

In ES6 I recommand you to see about *string interpolation* and *Array.reduce*

```js
const title = [
  'obi',
  'wan',
  'kenobi',
];

const mySelect = `<select>
  ${title.reduce((tmp, x) => `${tmp}<option>${x}</option>`, '')}
</select>`;

console.log(mySelect);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're approaching the problem in the wrong manner. Instead of trying to define a function which loops within a string you could use `map()` to loop over all `info` elements and generate the `<option>` elements from that.

```
var options = info.map(item => `<option>${item.title}</option>`);
let blokla = `<select>${options.join('')}</select>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't generate HTML - it's usually slower, it's more error prone, and harder to maintain. Generate DOM elements programmatically:

```js
const info = [
  {title: "one"},
  {title: "two"},
  {title: "three"},
  {title: "four"},
]

let blokla = document.createElement('select');

info
  .map(item => item.title) //get the titles
  .map(title => { //generate an option for each
    let option = document.createElement('option');
    option.textContent = title;
    
    return option;
  })
  .forEach(option => blokla.appendChild(option)); //add to select

//just to show what HTML this element would have
console.log(blokla.outerHTML);

//append the element
document.body.appendChild(blokla);
```

Or slightly more elegantly using jQuery:

```js
const info = [
  {title: "one"},
  {title: "two"},
  {title: "three"},
  {title: "four"},
]

let blokla = $("<select>");

info
  .map(item => item.title) //get the titles
  .map(title => $("<option>").text(title)) //generate an option for each
  .forEach(title => title.appendTo(blokla)); //add to select

//put on the page
$(document.body)
  .append(blokla);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var data= ['one','two','three','four'];
var html = "<select>"+generateOption(data)+"/<select>";
function generateOption(data)
{
  var returnHtml = "";
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
    returnHtml += "<option>"+data[i]+"</option>";
  return returnHtml;
}
console.log(html);
```

Try this

Comment: Please read [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @ScottMarcus ok ,  i read it,but i think my sort answer will help.

Comment: If you read it, you'd would know that your answer doesn't provide any context. Code only answers, like this don't let the OP know what was wrong with their code or how your code solves the problem. With no explanation, how will anyone learn and understand what you are providing? Remember, Stack Overflow isn't just to answer the question for the OP, it's a knowledge base for others who may come along with the same or similar problem in the future.

Comment: @ScottMarcus You're right ,i'll share my answers with more explanation ☺️